# Can't alter innerHTML of object variable

Tags: javascript, object, innerhtml

I have this code

```
var errorId = {
        name    :    document.getElementById('para_name').innerHTML,
        desc    :    document.getElementById('para_desc').innerHTML,
        photo   :    document.getElementById('para_photo').innerHTML,
        price   :    document.getElementById('para_price').innerHTML,
        cat     :    document.getElementById('para_cat').innerHTML
    };
    errorId.name = 'Hello There';
    // this works: document.getElementById('para_name').innerHTML = 'Hello';
```

And when I try to alter the innerHTML using the object accessor '.' I cannot change the innerHTML however, the commented line below works perfectly when the code is run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accessing `innerHTML` doesn't set a reference to the element, instead just returns the string representation of its html. So you can instead do:

```
var errorId = {
    name    :    document.getElementById('para_name'),
    desc    :    document.getElementById('para_desc'),
   ...
};
errorId.name.innerHTML = 'Hello There';
```

Or you could probably do:

```
 var errorId = {
    _name    :    document.getElementById('para_name'),
    _desc    :    document.getElementById('para_desc'),
    _photo   :    document.getElementById('para_photo'),
    ...
    name : function(value){
       if(this._name)
           this._name.innerHTML = value;
    }
    ...

};
errorId.name('Hello There');
```